# Change points to commas

Tags: jquery, latitude-longitude

I have an application that store the latitude and longitude like this 39.43433,-7.2232

This is to make it easier to copy and paste from google. The problem is that sometimes the string is like 39,43433,-7,2232.

How can I, with javascript / Jquery transform this string 39,43433,-7,2232 on this 39.43433,-7.2232.

We musr remember that we dont know how much numbers are in the beggining and in the end of the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know that there are either one or three commas.

If there are 3, then:

```
string = "39,43433,-7,2232"
parts = string.split(",")
fixedString = parts[0]+"."+parts[1]+","+parts[2]+"."+parts[3]
```

Will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace() with RegExps using the "g" flag.

Answer (score 0):

Replace every 1st coma with dot. By leaving alone every second comma you will make sure that seperation commas are left alone. Also this will probably work only if you have `1,111,2,222` and not `1.111,2.222`. Still you get the idea..

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '39,43433,-7,2232';
var patt = new RegExp("([-]?\\d+)\,([-]?\\d+)", "g");
var x = str.match(patt);
console.log(x);
// ["39,43433", "-7,2232"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, using regex groups:

```
var string = "39,43433,-7,2232"
string.replace(/([-\d]+),(\d+)(,)([-\d]+),(\d+)/g, "$1" + '.' + "$2$3$4" + '.'  + "$5")
```

This is using groups to do the reconcatenation of the string and is faster than string split and array join. But if you're more the object oriented kind of guy, you can go even simpler and more readable with ECMA-Script 5:

```
string.match(/(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)/g).
  map(function(e) { return e.replace(/,/, '.'); }).
  join(',')
```

Attention, you do have to have [map](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm) installed for browsers that [do not have support for ECMA Script 5](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) to maintain cross-browser compatibility. You can do that by adding this to your code

```
if (!('map' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.map= function(mapper, that /*opt*/) {
    var other= new Array(this.length);
    for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
        if (i in this)
            other[i]= mapper.call(that, this[i], i, this);
    return other;
  };
}
```